# Group list by element number

Tags: c#, linq

I have an integer list that contains about 60-70 elements. How can i get lists that contains 10 integer elements by using linq? If there are 68 elements then function should return 6 lists that contain 10 elements and 1 list that contains 8 elements.

Comment: Have you tried solving that on your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i = 0;
return items.GroupBy(x => i++ % 10);
```

Comment: You should not rely on that lambda only being called once per item.

Comment: Firstly, the ordering is changed, but that wasn't one of the requirements. However, for 69 items, this would give 5 groups of 10 and 2 groups of 9 objects, which doesn't match the question's requirements.

Comment: @sixlettervariables I've never heard that objection before, but it's a good point. @René I guess `/` is needed in place of `%` then.

Comment: I agree with rawling - division (casted/truncated) would work here.  @sixlettervariables - can you elaborate on the "once per item."  Is there something that says that the lambda must be determistic?

Comment: @b_levitt: besides relying on side effects in a lambda, you have no guarantee that [an implementation of `GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) does not call `keySelector` more than once per element in `source`.

Comment: @user7116 - My hopes would be that if MS required a deterministic expression that they would mention that in the documentation.  In any event this would address the problem I think:

Comment: var groups = list.Select(x => new { Grouping = count++ / 10, Value = x }).GroupBy(x => x.Grouping);

Answer (score 7):

You want the `Batch` operation of `MoreLinq`:

http://nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.Batch/

For example:

```
var batches = myIntegerList.Batch(10);

foreach (var batch in batches)
    foreach (int item in batch)
        // Do something with item
```

If you actually need to convert the sequences to `List<int>`:

```
var batches = myIntegerList.Batch(10, batch => batch.ToList());

foreach (var batch in batches) // batch is now a List<int>
    foreach (int item in batch)
```

Comment: +1 for not reinventing the wheel :)